# Hibernate or hsql does not respect column length

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hsqldb

I have an application that uses hibernate to generate tables (since my application is still under development) for HSQL db. In my domain model I have set

```
@Basic
@Column(name = "about", length = 10)
private String about;
```

When I open my db using DBVisualizer I can see that everything is set up properly except it is not working my column accepts values that are way over 10 characters long. When I try to run the query manually in the DBVisualier it fails as it should but hibernate lets it run.

Also very strange is when I use the file (in stead of in memory db) so that I can see the db structure and I point to the DBVisualizer it somehow breaks the connection so my changes from the Hibernate are not visible from that moment on. Everything still works I just cant see that changes in the DBVisualizer but I can in the application.

Anyone has any idea about this weird behavior?

cheers all

UPDATE

Hibernate configuration

```
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:mem:test</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">sa</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
    <property name="sql.enforce_strict_size">true</property>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem probably comes from a limitation in HSQLDB, described in [the documentation](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/1.8/guide/ch09.html#create_table-section):

> HSQLDB databases are initially created in a legacy mode that **does not
>   enforce column size and precision**. You can set the property:
>   sql.enforce_strict_size=true to enable this feature. When this
>   property has been set, Any supplied column size and precision for
>   numeric and character types (CHARACTER and VARCHAR) are enforced. Use
>   the command, SET PROPERTY "sql.enforce_strict_size" TRUE once before
>   defining the tables.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: I have added that but it did not do anything. I can still add more text then I should. The size is enforced if I do it using the tool such as DBVisualizer and I write the query, but if I use hibernate it is not

Comment: http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/1.8/guide/ch09.html#datatypes-section says that this property must be set right after creating the database, before adding data. Make sure you've followed this rule.

Comment: I have just added the property in the config file, so I guess it should be called when it is due. Also why would the DBVisulisator work with length in place and hibernate not :S Is it possible that the DBV is enforcing this and not the HSQL?

Comment: No idea. but I wouldn't *guess* it *should* be called. I would call it explicitely, before defining the tables, as recommended in the documentation.

Comment: how do I call it explicitly? Hibernate is generating everything for me. thx for help btw

Comment: As explained in the documentation I linked to: `SET PROPERTY "sql.enforce_strict_size" true`. Hibernate generates tables. But it doesn't create your database. Create your database, execute the above statement, then start your app.

Comment: I see. Ok when I have set the url to jdbc:hsqldb:mem:test;sql.enforce_strict_size=true it is working. Thanks for the help. cheers