# Expecting java.sql.SQLException value to large exception to be thrown by in-memory HSQL Database

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hsqldb, dump, pojo

I’m using hibernate as JPA provider for my project. In production my Java app with hibernate is running against a 11g Oracle DB. In production the

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

**Is not set** I manually written all the SQL scripts for making the data model.

Locally with JUnit i test my various hibernate POJOs and DAOs against a HSQL in-mem DB. Surely you can mock your returns but I found it more beautiful to test it this way. In the project test package I have a separately test.hibernate.cfg.xml configuration where the

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"> create</property>
<property name="sql.enforce_strict_size">true</property>
```

**are set**. I have a hibernate POJO BAG where the length of a REMARKS VARCHAR column is set by the **@COLUM{length = 128}** annotation. I also written a small Java method where you can dump the contents of a HSQL in mem-DB. Very handy if you want to debug your HSQL database. I want to test if restrictions are working on my class members and if the exception handling is sufficient on my DAO. I can see in the database dump that a BAG table is created and the max value of REMARKS is set to 128. I’m expecting a SQLException to be thrown but instead HSQL accepts a thousand A’s to be inserted in the REMARKS field. Why are there no restrictions on my REMARKS column in the HSQL database?

**AbstractTestDao:**

```
public abstract class AbstractTestDao {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() {
        //Start HSQL database 
        HsqlServerUtil.getInstance().start("mem:testdb");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void teardownClass() {
        //End HSQL database 
        HsqlServerUtil.getInstance().stop();
    }

    void setUpOperation() {
        //Set up test.hibernate.cfg.xml
        HibernateUtil.setSessionFactory(configureSessionFactory());
    }

    /**
     * Generic method for persisting entities into database.
     *
     * @param entity Java object from a (hibernate) class annotated with @Entity
     */
    <T> void persistEntity(T entity) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.persist(entity);
        session.beginTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }

    /**
     * Generic method for retrieving entities from database.
     *
     * @param cls Object class
     * @param id  Entity unique identifier (Primary Key)
     * @return Casted Entity object from db
     */
    <T> T getEntityById(Class<T> cls, Long id) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        T entity = cls.cast(session.load(cls, id));
        session.close();
        return entity;
    }

    /**
    * Don't forget to close your connection so that the in-mem db can release it resources.
    *
    * @return Connection object to the in-memory db HyperSQL.
    * @throws SQLException
    */
    public static Connection getNewConn() throws SQLException {
        return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb;shutdown=false", "SA", "");
    }

    /**
     * Makes a script from the current in-memory database and place a txt file in a directory.
     * The script describes the current in-mem db including constrains.
     *
     * @param testName A String representing the junit test name used for describing the file.
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    void createDatabaseScript(final String testName) throws SQLException {

        final String filePath = new File("").getAbsolutePath();
        final String targetDir = "/target/Temp/Databasedump/";
        final String directoryPath = filePath.concat(targetDir);
        final File directory = new File(directoryPath);
        if (!directory.exists()) {
            directory.mkdir();
        }

        final String fileName = uniqueFileNameGenerator(directoryPath, testName);

        final Connection conn = getNewConn();
        Statement st = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try {
            st = conn.createStatement();
            //Example: st.executeQuery("SCRIPT '../Temp/dump4.txt'")
            final String sqlStatement = String.format("SCRIPT '%s%s'", directoryPath, fileName);
            rs = st.executeQuery(sqlStatement);

        } finally {
            if (st != null) {
                st.close();
            }
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.close();
            }
        }       


    }

    /**
     * Search for a unique filename in a directory with 1 to 2147483647 (Integer.MAX_VALUE) possibilities per date.
     * May throw a StackOverflowError if all 2147483646 file names are given away.
     *
     * @param directoryPath - String representing the directory you want to use.
     * @param name          - String representing the filename you want to use.
     * @return String representing a unique filename
     */
    private String uniqueFileNameGenerator(final String directoryPath, final String name) {

        final DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        final String todayDate = dateFormat.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        final Integer randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1);
        final String fileName = name + "_" + todayDate + "_" + randomNumber + ".txt";

        File file = new File(directoryPath + fileName);

        if (file.exists()) {
            return uniqueFileNameGenerator(directoryPath, name);
        }
        return fileName;
    }   

}

<br>
<strong>BAG POJO:</strong>
</br>

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "BAG")
    public class Bag implements Serializable {

        public static final int FIELD_LENGTH_REMARKS = 128;
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @SequenceGenerator(name = "BAG_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "BAG_ID_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "BAG_ID_GENERATOR")
        private Long id;

        @Column(name = "REMARKS", length = FIELD_LENGTH_REMARKS)
        private String remarks;

        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(final Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getRemarks() {
            return remarks;
        }

        public void setRemarks(String remarks) {
            this.remarks = remarks;
        }   
    }
```

**JUnit BagDao test:**

```
public class BagDaoTest extends AbstractTestDao {

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        //Setup HSQL tables every JUnit test
        setUpOperation();
    }

    @Test(expected=SQLException.class)
    public void remarkBagValueExceeded() throws SQLException {

        Bag bag = new Bag();
        final char[] array = new char[1000];
        Arrays.fill(array, 'A');        

        bag.setRemarks(String.valueOf(array));

        persistEntity(bag);
        //Expecting a java.sql.SQLException value to large exception here.

        Bag retrieved = getEntityById(Bag.class, bag.getId());

        Assert.assertNotNull(retrieved);
        System.out.println("Id was: " + retrieved.getId());
        System.out.println("Remarks is: " + retrieved.getRemarks());
        try {
            createDatabaseScript("remarkBagValueExceeded");
        }catch (SQLException sqe) {
            System.out.println("Sql exception was thrown when trying to dump the DB");
        }
    }
}
```

**Program output:**

```
Id was: 1
Remarks is: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA.. //many more A
```

**DB dump:**

```
CREATE SCHEMA PUBLIC AUTHORIZATION DBA
CREATE SEQUENCE BAG_ID_SEQ AS INTEGER START WITH 1
CREATE MEMORY TABLE BAG(ID BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, REMARKS VARCHAR(128))
CREATE USER SA PASSWORD ""
GRANT DBA TO SA
SET SCHEMA PUBLIC
INSERT INTO COM_SEALBAG VALUES(1,'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA..//many more A')
```

**HSQL DB version:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.0.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate or hsql does not respect column length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765796/hibernate-or-hsql-does-not-respect-column-length)

Comment: Dawid Pytel sql.enforce_strict_size is set. And you can also see in HSQL DB that column is created with this restriction.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Have you tried passing this parameter as connection parameter, something like: `<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:mem:.;sql.enforce_strict_size=true</property>`

Comment: I tried that one it take the configuration but I can still fill in thousand A's